# How to create Task<T> in runtime?

Tags: c#, reflection, runtime, task

Is there any way to create `Task<T>` in runtime where `T` is the type known only in runtime? I would like to create `Task<T>` with default value for `T` but after obtaining default value for `T` and use `Task.FromResult(default_value)`  I’m getting `Task<object>` instead of `Task<T>` because in most cases default value is null. Any Idea to fix this?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var type = typeof(string); // fin real code type resolved in runtime
            var default_value = GetDefaultValue(type);
            var test = Task.FromResult(default_value); //Task<object> - how to get Task<T>
        }

        public static object GetDefaultValue(Type t)
        {
            if (t.IsValueType)
            {
                return Activator.CreateInstance(t);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please share your code. The default value for a reference type is `null`. I'm not sure what you want to fix.

Comment: Why don't you know the _type_ of your return value?

Comment: To get the default value of a type, you can just use `default(T)` - no need for a function for that.

Comment: With your updated answer, you should probably use `nameof(GetDefaultTask)` rather than `"GetDefaultTask"`. It just means if the method is renamed it will catch it, if you use a tool to find references to the method it will find it, it won't claim it's an unused method, etc.

Comment: Yes you are right - it is only fast dev :)

Comment: It's not appropriate to edit an answer into your question.  If you want to post an answer to your question, post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics are used for compile time type checking. You can't define a `<T>` at runtime. The best you could do is `Task<object>` with a cast to the type you want after `await`ing it, or maybe a `Task<dynamic>`.

I'm not sure why you want to do this.

If you can supply a generic type at compile time, you can just do

```
public Task<T> GetDefaultTask<T>() {
    return Task.FromResult(default(T));
}
```

Comment: Not exacly what I need but give me an inspiration ;) I will updated my question with answer